# Regarding Struts configuration files

Tags: struts2, struts, struts-1

Where do we need to put the struts configuration files in a web application? And, what is the differences between struts.xml and struts-config.xml? For Struts 2 applications, which one we should use?

Thanks.

Comment: Here is part of your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988742/struts-xml-and-struts-config-xml

Comment: And, how do the web container know it? Do we need any entries in the web.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in Vinodh's link, `struts.xml` is the default name of the configuration file in Struts2. `struts-config.xml` is a Struts1 configuration file, and should not be used in Struts2.

Your `struts.xml` file should be at the root of your class path so that once your web app is built, it will be located in WEB-INF/classes. You can accomplish this by placing it in your source folder. If you use the Maven 2 Standard Directory Layout, then you would place it in src/main/resources.

Comment: Thanks to both. And, how do the web container know it? Do we need any entries in the web.xml?

Comment: You need to define the Struts2 `Filter` in the web.xml, but that's it. When Struts2 starts up, it will look for a file named `struts.xml`.